# Setting up keith-wood CountDown on Static HTML Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, count, installation

I'm using HTML Static Page for my website index, and I want to setup Keith-wood countdown.
It has some defaults and I cant find(?) them, here is the code in index.html :

```
<div id="container-counter">
  <div id="defaultCountdown"></div>
</div>
```

Where can I change the target date in default var?

-
Edit: Since the defaults cant be found, it means that the setup code is not visible and was likely not included as it should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.countdown.css"> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.plugin.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
```

The default JS example for this plugin from http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html reads:

```
var newYear = new Date(); 
newYear = new Date(newYear.getFullYear() + 1, 1 - 1, 1); 
$('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: newYear});
```

With all of this is in place, the question can now be answered:

***Where can I change the target date in default var?***

Answer (score 2):

After a quick look, Keith-wood countdown works as follows (example code they provide that works with your code):

```
newYear = new Date(); 
var newYear = new Date(newYear.getFullYear() + 1, 1 - 1, 1); 
$('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: newYear});
```

If I understand your question right, then you simply need to change the code at line 2:

```
newYear = new Date(newYear.getFullYear() + 1, 1 - 1, 1);
```

Since this sets the `newYear` variable to the date you want to count down to. So to set the date as per your question you simply need to properly set the JS constructor for the new `Date` on that line:

```
new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
```

Hence if you are counting down to a launch at 10AM on the 15th December 2014 then you will just set it to:

```
new Date(2014, 12, 15, 10, 0, 0, 0)
```

If you want to know more about the basic set-up, not just changing the dates you can find that [here](http://keith-wood.name/countdownRef.html) on keith-wood's website.

Hope that helps!